# multiple List submit

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

i have .jsp file like this

```
<input type="text" name="type">
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="question[0].title">
     <div>
       <input type="text" name="question[0].option[0].name">
       <input type="text" name="question[0].option[1].name">
     </div>
   <input type="text" name="question[1].title">
     <div>
       <input type="text" name="question[1].option[0].name">
       <input type="text" name="question[1].option[1].name">
     </div>
  </div>
```

how to submit by post method ?
and my java entity like this

> entity ---------->

```
public class Survey{
  private String type ;
  private List<Question> question;
   ...get ...set

}
public class Question{
  private String title ;
  private List<Option> option;
   ...get ...set

}
public class Option{
 private String name ;
   ...get ...set
}

> Controller ------>

    @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public BaseResponse save(Survey survey) {

    }

> Js---->

$.ajax({
            url:mainForm.attr('action'),
            type:'post',
            data:formObj
```

"type" can receive value from jsp, why "question[0].xx" can't receive
how to change it

Comment: It seems  everything is fine. Can you post your java classes related to this fully?

Comment: what classes? controller?

Comment: dto and controller--better you can add ajax too

Comment: I made a mistake , getter setter not regenerate after change property . thank u all the same